# Postman Error: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=407

Tags: postman

I am using the desktop version of Postman at a client site to test an API. However, I am unable to access any SSL sites in Postman, such as the Git Hib API: https://api.github.com/users/karlgjertsen

However, I can make the same API call through Chrome, so this is Postman specific.

I assume it is down to proxy settings, but I am not sure how to view or update these in Postman. Has anyone had any experienced something similar?

Comment: For me, it just worked after I restarted Postman.

Answer (score 71):

I turned OFF both Global Proxy Configuration and Use System Proxy in Settings->Proxy tab in Postman and it started to work.

Comment: this worked for me. I disabled the option *Use System Proxy*

Answer (score 22):

Follow these steps on postman -
Go to **file=>Settings => Proxy (Tab)** and uncheck the **"Use System Proxy"** checkbox. That should work

[image]

Comment: merci! it was also the right way for me

Answer (score 18):

This solved my issue :

The option "**Respect HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY, and NO_PROXY environment variables**." was selected by default in the proxy settings. I turned off this option and it worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

Posting as the other solutions presented in this thread did not work in our corporate environment. We have a proxy configured on the network which uses Windows Default Credentials (username and password) for authentication. For whatever reason the browser knows how to pass these details with each request but postman does not by default.

Solution was to update the Default Proxy Configuration under **settings -> proxy -> Default Proxy Configuration -> Tick 'This proxy requires authentication'** then enter Windows Username and Password. Leave **Use the system proxy** and **Add a custom proxy configuration** settings disabled.

From the Windows start menu go to **Change proxy settings** and configure the host and port there.

[image]

Comment: Almost 3 years later, this answer helped me out a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This turned out to be a local security policy that was applied to the machine in use. The local SSL proxy had a policy applied and it would not allow me to make a secure connection unless it was through a web browser.

Comment: so there is no way to do it through the app? I just get the same error and I thought it is because of proxy too. But my administrator don't let to install chrome extension, so I'm confused...

Comment: Where can you check for this in the local security policy?

Comment: The local policy was added by the IT team and I had to request an exemption. Typical issue you will run in to in a corporate environment.

Comment: What is the name of the policy, if it has a name? This is in the proxy software itself, right, not at the OS level, correct? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my case I turned off the 'Add a custom proxy configuration' in File -> Settings -> Proxy tab and it solved the issue. No idea why it was on.

Answer (score 0):

For me, none of the options above worked. The 'Use the system proxy' setting ought to respect the HTTP_PROXY environment variables, however the proxy may still need a login if you are accessing from inside a secure corporate network.

I took value in the Environment variable HTTP_PROXY (or HTTPS_PROXY)....

[image: HTTP_PROXY Environment Variable]

...and used it to setup a 'custom proxy configuration'

[image: Postman Settings Add a custom proxy configuration]

The above worked to me on the example given at [https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/soap/making-soap-requests/#:~:text=Postman%20can%20make%20HTTP%20calls%20using%20SOAP%2C%20a,Select%20POST%20from%20the%20request%20method%20dropdown%20list](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/soap/making-soap-requests/#:%7E:text=Postman%20can%20make%20HTTP%20calls%20using%20SOAP%2C%20a,Select%20POST%20from%20the%20request%20method%20dropdown%20list).

(Service endpoint: https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/NumberConversion.wso)

Answer (score 0):

On Postman desktop version, setting is required to be updated.
Turn off "Use System Proxy" in the settings area.

Go to Settings (Gear Icon, Beside Invite Button)
Then go to Proxy menu item and TURN OFF Use System Proxy

See screenshot of the desktop version
[On Newer Version of Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hK31.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).