# I can't send GET request with Https though it works with http (PHP)

Tags: php, api, https, get, request

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');

header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");



include_once '../config/Database.php';
include_once '../class/verse.php';
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

$verse = new verse($db);

if(!isset($_GET['book']) || !isset($_GET['chapter']))
{  die(); }
  
$stmt = $verse->getVersesByChapter($_GET['book'],$_GET['chapter']);
$num = $stmt->rowCount();
  
if($num>0){
  
    // verses array
    $verses_arr=array();
    $verses_arr["records"]=array();
  
     while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
      extract($row);
  
        $verse_item=array(
            "id" =>  $row['verse_id'],
            "bible_version_id" =>  $row['bible_ver_id'],
            "book" => $row['verse_book'],
            "chapter" => $row['verse_chapter'],
            "part" => $row['verse_part'],
            "number" => $row['verse_number'],
            "filename" => $row['verse_filename'],
            "lyrics" => $row['verse_lyrics']
        );
  
        array_push($verses_arr["records"], $verse_item);
    }
  
    // set response code - 200 OK
    http_response_code(200);
  
    // make it json format
    echo json_encode($verses_arr);
}
  
else{
    // set response code - 404 Not found
    http_response_code(404);
  
    // tell the user verses do not exist
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Verses do not exist."));
}
?>
```

I finished working on this and tested it locally (Localhost), it works with both HTTP/HTTPS.
I put everything on the server, but each time I try the send a GET request with "https://hostname/..." I get this error right here.

```
Error: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=407
```

I'm testing requests with POSTMAN and it works when I send request with HTTP to the server.
What should I do?
Thanks.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44945663/postman-error-tunneling-socket-could-not-be-established-statuscode-407

Comment: I'm already using a custom Proxy since I'm working from home. So Global proxy is deactivated.